# Symbol conflicts when integrating TensorFlowLiteTaskVision via CocoaPods and TensorFlowLiteBenchmarkC manually in iOS

Tags: ios, tensorflow, tensorflow-lite

I'm working on an iOS app where I aim to benchmark a custom **TensorFlowLite** model for image classification. I'm using two libraries:

`TensorFlowLiteTaskVision` added via CocoaPods for image classification.
`TensorFlowLiteBenchmarkC`, an Objective-C framework, added manually for benchmarking.
When I integrate these libraries separately, everything works fine. However, when both are added to the same workspace, I encounter the following errors:

```
Undefined symbol: _OBJC_CLASS_$_GMLImage
Undefined symbol: _OBJC_CLASS_$_TFLClassifications
```

(and a few more similar ones).

It seems there's a symbol conflict or some missing symbols between the two libraries. I've tried using the -exclude_symbol linker flag without success.

Is there a way to exclude specific classes or resolve this conflict in another manner? Any guidance or workaround would be greatly appreciated.